# Checkboxlist inside a table td breaking the text into next line in IE7

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a checkboxlist inside a 'td' with fixed width of 160px. The checkboxlist is showing fine and taking auto with in FF,chrome,IE8 and IE9

```
    <table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
          <tr>

            <td style="width:160px;"> 
              <label class="tdLabel">my chekcbox:</label><br />
              <asp:CheckBoxList id="chk1" AutoPostBack="True" EnableViewState="true" CellPadding="5" CellSpacing="5"
                                RepeatColumns="1" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Flow" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="chk1_SelectedIndexChanged">
              </asp:CheckBoxList>
           </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

In FF text next to checkbox for each item is showing in one line. But in IE7 some of the text breaking into next line. I tried

```
float:left
text-align:left
clear:both
display:inline
```

on 'td' and checkboxlist also. nothing is working. Please help.

EDIT:

```
<td style="width:160px;white-space: nowrap;"> 
          <label class="tdLabel">my chekcbox:</label><br />
          <span id="xxxx"><input id="ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder4_ContentPlaceHolder2_chk1_0" type="checkbox"  /><label >Paln text1 goes here</label><br /><input id="ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder4_ContentPlaceHolder2_chk1_1" type="checkbox"  /><label >Paln text2 goes here</label>
```

Comment: could you provide the output html rather than the asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `white-space: nowrap;` in css

that should fix the problem:)

For ie7 wrap your text in p tags and then add the `white-space: nowrap;` to the p tags

Comment: Now it is acting strange, after adding this  white-space: nowrap  on td, when i load the page the problem is still there, but when i open the developers tool and uncheck the width, the text is in one line, but width is more than i need, so when i check the with style back again it is fixing the problem. But if i reload the page fix is gone.

Comment: are you using a stylesheet or are you putting the css right in the html?

Comment: I am actually setting inline width for each td, but white-space: nowrap style from style sheet, because I have a class assigned to each td.

Comment: i found the problem look at the answer.

Comment: make sure to add css directly to p tags not td tags ie7 has glitches with the td tags.